# Why Gmail SMTP Stopped Working?

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I wrote a windows base application with C# which sends email from a unique address to another unique address every 5 minutes using google smtp. I installed it in 5 Systems of my Company.
It worked for about 500 messages.
today I recieved a "delivery failure" message and it stopped working.
the message was

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
> my email address
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
>   Message rejected.  See http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=69585 for more information.

I know Gmail blocked my address. but Is there any way to reactive it? I just using two email addresses.

Comment: Google doesn't wan gmail to be a spam host - good for them! Anyway, *follow* the link Google provided for what events (e.g. "spam detection") caused this block and how it may be possible to remove it (yes, it does include that information).

Comment: yes it's because of daily sending limits. and I think there is no way. I just have to wait til the end of the day or using multi mail acounts and switch between them when a limit error occures.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are using the first email account to broadcast a message, and the second email account to receive those message, which is a lazy way to solve the issue you have at hand and is prone to problems just like the one you've just witnessed. Sending out 500 notifications to a single email address, from a single email address will always raise red flags.

You have two options, you can either carry on using SMTP by using a different service provider and risk service disruptions as well as having your IP being blacklisted or you can create a simple API which the client applications can subscribe to.